# Can't push a view onto searchResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a TableViewController, a SearchResultsController and a WebViewController. When I click on a cell in the TableViewController it pushes the WebViewController opening a url that is related to the cell.

The TableViewController has a UISearchController which filters the results into the SearchResultsController however when a cell is clicked in the SearchResultsController the WebViewController doesn't get pushed.

Here is the code for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the SearchResultsController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    NSString *extensionURL = (self.searchResults[indexPath.row])[@"url"];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.baseurl.com"];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:extensionURL relativeToURL:baseURL];

    webViewController.title = (self.searchResults[indexPath.row])[@"title"];
    NSLog(@"%@", URL);
    webViewController.URL = URL;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController
                                         animated:YES];

}
```

I included the NSLog to see if anything happened when a cell was clicked and it does display the url in the console. This makes me think the problem is with the navigationController.

Looking online it seems that the UISearchController should be wrapped in a UISearchContainerViewController which should then be put in the navigationController. I'm still new to app development and can't figure out how or where to do this.

I call my SearchResultsController in the viewDidLoad of my TableViewController like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SearchResultsViewController *controller = [[SearchResultsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self addObserver:controller forKeyPath:@"results" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController: controller];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES; 

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
    searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar;
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    UITextField *searchField = [searchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
    searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;

}
```

Is this where I should be embedding my SearchResultsController?

Comment: You use self.navigationController in your first block of code related to SearchResultsController. Make sure that navigationController is the one you want, and it should work.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate a little on what you mean in regards to self.navigationController?

Comment: The searchResultsController's navigationController is different than the TableViewController's navigationController. It sounds like you want to use the TableViewController's self.navigationController

Comment: I think I see your point but I'm still not sure what I need to do to fix it. Is it possible to use TableViewController's navigationController or does SearchResultsController need to be embedded in its own navigationController?

Comment: Yes you can use TableViewController's navigationController; self.searchResultsController.parentViewController.navigationController (make sure the parentViewController is the TableViewController)

Comment: What if TableViewController isn't the parentViewController? I put 
    `NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController);` to find out what it is and it says the parent is "UISearchController".

Comment: Then you need to find a way to get the TableViewController's navigationController some other way; since your post does not accurately reflect your code I can't really help you out any more than that

Answer (score 18):

When doing search you will present the NewModalViewController so its simple all you need to do is some steps for pushing viewcontroller when you present search controller

1)self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

After this you should push your viewcontroller like

2) [self.presentingViewController.navigationController pushViewController:sec animated:YES];

Note:Present modalviewcontroller doesnt have Navigation controller so normal push coding wont work as it is not allocated to navigation.

Enjoy.....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a property in your SearchResultsController:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navController;
```

Then in your updateSearchResultsForSearchController in your TableViewController set the navController =  self.navigationController.

Then you can do this in your SearchResultsController's didSelectRowForIndexPath:

```
[self.navController pushViewController:webViewController
                                     animated:YES];
```

This approach worked for me after failing to get Arun's above mentioned solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

In view controller where you present searchResultsController use: `definesPresentationContext = true`

Next in searchResultsController you push another controller like this:
`presentingViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(anotherVC, animated: false)`